# Oh Unity Launcher scrambled with color dots after log on or restart

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

The left hand side Unity launch bar is color scrambled after reboot, or log on. When touching it with the mouse arrow, it comes back to normal. I installed gnome shell color before this started happening. I will uninstall gnome shell color & see if this problem goes away. Any one ever see this happen. I run a Nvidia 550ti ge-force graphic card. I have the latest 295.33 driver from Nvidia installed and it does show activated in my restricted driver window. Oh yeah, before you inform me, I can tell you that yes, I do see the instructions to report bugs to the correct source. But I really don't know if this is a bug or not. Could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

If unity is messed up then you have to reset it. Do this by typing this command in the terminal:

```
unity --reset
```

If you want to reset the Unity Launcher icons (dock bar on the left) to their initial state, run the following command:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, However; in resetting unity, I risk a system crash as I am running compiz. I have a big fear of using the reset --Unity or any other window decorator command in 11.10. So instead, I uninstalled (gnome color chooser) and my problem was gone. I re-installed out of curiosity & the problem was still gone and color chooser working correctly now. My Unity was never messed up, it was just the launch bar had scrambled color dots on startup. Once I touched it with the mouse it disappeared. So re-installing gnome color chooser fixed it. Thanks anyways for your help. James

Comment: Its OK. You are welcome. But remember this commands because this will help you in future if things messed up......